# Create Event from Spreasheeet to Google Calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scheduled-tasks, google-calendar-api

I have this [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12A2pq5PlbXEgMaZyrDTK5LmLmBAX4QBLTxNJ6DU7Nw4/edit?usp=sharing)

With 2 columns for due dates of my tasks.

How do I create a script that can create the events based on these due dates and notify me some days before that they are due?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Creating Events from Spreadsheet**

`getEvent()` reads the spreadsheet below which is very similar to the one you provided with a few modifications as I will describe.  I added a event title and description column.  The Scheduled column provides the capability to prevent duplicating events when the script is run again.  The Schedule column is a datavalidation ('Yes'/'No').

[image]

```
function getEventData() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('EventData');
  var sr=4;//data start row
  var lc=8;//last column
  var hA=sh.getRange(sr-1,1,1,lc).getValues()[0];
  var idx={};//correlate column header to evA indices
  hA.forEach(function(e,i){idx[e]=i;});//This creates an object for identifying array indices through the use of Column header name making it a bit easier to associate data with their value descriptions
  var rg=sh.getRange(sr,1,sh.getLastRow()-sr+1,lc );
  var evA=rg.getDisplayValues();
  evA.forEach(function(r,i){
    if(r[idx.Scheduled]!='Yes') {
      var eObj={};
      eObj.start=r[idx.Start];
      eObj.end=r[idx.End];
      eObj.title=r[idx.Title];
      eObj.description=Utilities.formatString('<b>Name:</b> %s,%s<br /><b>Age:</b> %s<br /><b>Description:</b> %s',r[idx.Last],r[idx.First],r[idx.Age],r[idx.Description]);
      if(createEventWithReminders(eObj)) {
        sh.getRange(i+sr,idx.Scheduled+1).setValue('Yes');
      }else{
        sh.getRange(i+sr,idx.Scheduled+1).setValue('No');
      }
    }
  });
}
```

The createEventWithReminders function takes the Object and creates an event on whatever calendar you specify with the calendar id that you must provide.

```
//{start:dd/MM/yyyy,end:dd/MM/yyyy,title:string,description:string}
function createEventWithReminders(eObj)  {
  if(eObj.start && eObj.end && eObj.title && eObj.description) {
    var minute=1;
    var hour=60*minute;
    var day=24*hour;
    var week=7*day;
    var cal=CalendarApp.getCalendarById('Enter your calendar id');
    var sA=eObj.start.split('/');//splits the date string into fullyear,month and day
    var start=new Date(sA[2],sA[1]-1,sA[0]);//creates the start date notice the month-1
    var eA=eObj.end.split('/');
    var end=new Date(eA[2],eA[1]-1,eA[0]);
    var event=cal.createEvent(eObj.title, start, end);
    event.setDescription(eObj.description)
    event.setTitle(eObj.title)
    event.addEmailReminder(day);//creates a one day prior reminder
    event.addEmailReminder(week);//creates a one week prior reminder
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

Animation:

[image]

[create event](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createEvent(String,Date,Date))

[add email reminders](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#addEmailReminder(Integer))